New passport but documents have old passport number
So, I am applying for a China business visa from Pakistan and it requires police verification and COVID-19 certificates. My records have an old passport number and I am now using a new passport with a new number. Will it create any issues while applying for a visa?

If you join a copy of the previous passport, you should be absolutely fine with that
